# When I type "java -version", where is it pulling that information from?

Tags: java, bash, unix, command-line-interface

```
users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

As shown above, when I type "java -version" it returns this info. What is happening in bash when I hit enter and then this info pops up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on you environment path variable, the command line will look for the executable and run it with the argument -version

Not sure about Mac, but on Linux "which java" should give you the path to the executable that the bash is using

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the information comes from /sun/misc/Version.class in the rt.jar file.  I haven't been able to trace the path by which the JVM gets this information when you run `java -version`, but certainly the literal strings we are looking for are present in that class ... and not in the `java` binary itself.

(This is on a Linux machine with OpenJDK Java 8)

Comment: So I guess getting a little deeper, where is it pulling the "version" information from when you pass it in as an argument?  Wherever I installed the JDK on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed java into your machine and set your `java` path to the environment variable on any of the `Operating System` and type

```
java -version //command to use show Installed Java Version on Console.
```

you will get Installed java Version as an Output (Copied from your Example) .
Here `java` is used to invoke `jvm` and `-version` is Option.

```
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

If your machine doesnot have jave then it will show Result like

```
java is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

there are various more options are available with this `java` Command . Some of the Options are

```
-d32
-d64
-server
-hotspot
 ...... // more than 20 options are available.
```

> These options have a special purpose to gather different kind of Information regading System .

Comment: Thanks!  But how is getting the version information?  Which folder is it pulling it out of?  if I do an update will the correct information be present when I do "java -version"?

Comment: suppose you have installed different version of java but `java -version` only  gives output which folder address you have passed in `Environment Variable` actually. Thanks.

Comment: @vkapustin there are various ways of environment variable path setting can be achieve refer this >> http://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-set-path-in-java

Comment: on Windows, you could type `where java`. On *nix `which java`. Both commands will point you to the folder of the binaries that were run.